# Adobe After Effects CC Transformation Speed

Tags: transformation, after-effects, creative-cloud

I have a logo, moving center of the screen to the left hand side of the screen. It's a fairly smooth transformation however I want the motion to start slowly, speed up to a maximum then slow back down before completing it's transformation. How can this be achieved? I have Googled but not found any luck, I think I'm just not using the correct search criteria

Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on a keyframe. You have a number of options available, including Keyframe Assistant> "Easy Ease". This gives you "slow-ins" and "slow-outs" to your keyframes. To increase the eases, right click on a keyframe, select "Keyframe Velocity...", and if the keyframe is the outgoing one (the first one), enter a greater value in the "outgoing influence" (like, say, 70%). Play around with these values. As usual, for anything in AE, there are several ways to accomplish a task. Two other ways of doing this are a) using the tangent controls in the Comp Viewer window, and b) using the graph editor (see graphic).
[image]